# Android Viewpager Call Webservice

Tags: android, multithreading, android-viewpager

I have override below method in extended PageAdapter class.
I need to do as mentioned in comments. 
Show progress dialog until webservice call finished.
After gettting data from web servcie create view in canvas and return.

problem is that How can I stop return statement until webservice call. because If  I call webservice in different thread, It returns view before webservice call finished. And I cannot call webservice in main thread.

Thanks.

```
@Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {

        // showProgress dialog Step-1
        // call webservice in thread Step-2
        // dismiss progress dialog Step-3
        // Create View in canvass and add in collection.addView(v, 0); Step-4
        // return v; Step-5
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add a Fragment to your Viewpager to call webservice and create view, by creating an adapter extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter. then you can override getItem(int position) method to create a Fragment to call service then create view. That sounds more reasonable to me:)

Comment: Thanks 4 ans. bro. but I didn't get what exactly you want to say to do